# Adding elements to a new created vector in python

Tags: python, vector

I have a vector as follows

```
vector_partitions = [[4,1,1],[3,2,1],[2,2,2]].
```

I want to create a new vector by modifying `vector_partitions` by dividing 6 by each element of each vector element in vector_partitions, so for instance my new vector should be `pre_final = [[1.5,6,6], [2,3,6], [3,3,3]]`.

The code I wrote for this is the following:

```
vector_partitions = part(int(x),int(y))

length = len(vector_partitions)

for i in range(0, length):
    length_new_vect = len(vector_partitions[1])
    pre_final = []
    pre_final.extend([int(x)/p for p in vector_partitions[i]])

print(pre_final)
```

However, I end up getting just the last element of whay my pre_final should be, so I end up getting only the vector `[3,3,3]`. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assign `[]` to `pre_final` in each iteration and replacing the inserted values. You have to initialize `pre_final` outside the loop. Also you are using `extend` that concatenates 2 lists. You need to use `append` to push the new list in the end of `pre_final`. This fix your initial code

```
pre_final = []
for i in range(len(vector_partitions)):
    pre_final.append([6.0 / x for x in vector_partitions[i]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need to use `range` or `extend` to do this. Simply use list comprehensions.

```
>>> vector_partitions = [[4, 1, 1], [3, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2]]
>>> pre_final = [[6/i for i in item] for item in vector_partitions]
>>> pre_final
[[1.5, 6.0, 6.0], [2.0, 3.0, 6.0], [3.0, 3.0, 3.0]]
```